# Is there any way to force update my OpenGL?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to make apps with Kivy in Python, but when i run an app. It says minimum OpenGL version required is OpenGL 2....But i have OpenGL 1.1.
I tried going to the device manager and looking for updates, but it says my graphics drivers are fully updated. Is there any way to run kivy apps?

I am using windows 10 64bit with python 3.70
latest version of kivy